# How do I keep line-height only on the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a row of 3 elements:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="item-one">
        <p>text here <span> more text here </span> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-two">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="item-three">
    <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

And such, I center these vertically using `line-height`:

```
.header {
   line-height: 100px;
}
```

Which looks exactly like this:

[image: How it looks normally.]

My problem is that I want my `item-one` text on two rows, as such, I'd like to transform `item-one` to:

```
<div class="item-one">
    <div class="one">text here</div>
    <div class="two">more text here</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that each block of text now has an inherent line-height of 100px, making it look like this:

[image: How the items look with two blocks on top of each other.]

Now, I reckon this would happen with any two elements that are under each other div, not just text, because each inherits the line-height, as such:

How can I keep line-height only on the parent-divs `item-one`, `item-two`, `item-three` for centering purposes and leaving the childs alone? Resetting line-height inside childs doesn't work.

Comment: Your layout might be easier to achieve and manage using flexbox -->https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ -- If you want to stick with `line-height` you should be able to reset the child `line-height` by using `px` values, instead of relative values.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I keep line-height only on the parent div?

Just reset the `line-height` on the child `div`.

So let's say you had the following code to start with:

```
.header {
  line-height: 100px; /* parent line-height */
  ...
}
```

```css
.header {
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.header > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="item-one">
    <div>text here
      <p> more text here </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-two">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x50">
  </div>
  <div class="item-three">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x70">
  </div>
</div>
```

In order to fix this - just reset the `line-height` on the .item-one `div`

```
.item-one {
  line-height: normal;  /* child line-height */
}
```

```css
.header {
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.header:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.header>div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item-one {
  line-height: normal;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="item-one">
    <div>text here
      <p> more text here </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-two">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80x50">
  </div>
  <div class="item-three">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x70">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would switch `line-height` for `flexbox` to align items vertically:

You can check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oypepsw2/)

These are the styles I have used for the HTML you have provided:

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.item-one {
  span {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's amazing, but unfortunately, I can't use flexbox due to it not being as widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting line-height inside childs *should work*

Even though `item two` has *line-height: 100px* that does not affect *line-height* of child elements

Check this example below:

```css
.item-one{
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item-two{
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.item-two > div{
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-one">
    <div class="one">text here</div>
    <div class="two">more text here</div>
</div>

<div class="item-two">
    <div class="one">text here</div>
    <div class="two">more text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't my issue, as per your answer, the line-height to the `.item-two` is still 30px, when it should be 100px;, the childs should have their own 30px line-height, but the whole parent div now is on 30px. To add more, with this solution, the item is no longer centered with the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

If flexbox is not an option, you could vertically center the text using `position: absolute`.

In the snippet below the `line-height` has been reset, and the containing div has been vertically-centered.

```css
.header {
  line-height: 100px;
  background: pink;
}

.header .item-one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}

.header .item-one div {
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div class="item-one">
    <div class="one">text here</div>
    <div class="two">more text here</div>
  </div>
  <div class=" item-two ">
    <img src=" ">
  </div>
  <div class="item-three ">
    <img src=" ">
  </div>
</div>
```